# Compare two tables based on lastmodified column?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to check tickets group by month and year

```
SELECT 
    MONTH((lastmodified)) as month, 
    YEAR((lastmodified)) as year,
    COUNT(num_of_tickets) as tickets
    FROM visitors_2013
    GROUP BY 
    MONTH((lastmodified)), 
    YEAR((lastmodified))
```

this return something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => 1
            [year] => 2013
            [tickets] => 1521
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => 2
            [year] => 2013
            [tickets] => 513
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => 12
            [year] => 2012
            [tickets] => 146
        )

)
```

I have put this in a php function so i can get the data per year (data is stored in a seperate table per year).
I call function get_ticket_per_year($year) twice for 2013 and 2014

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => 1
            [year] => 2013
            [tickets] => 1521
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => 2
            [year] => 2013
            [tickets] => 513
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => 12
            [year] => 2012
            [tickets] => 146
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => 12
            [year] => 2013
            [tickets] => 26
        )

)
```

And i like to compare month-year-total tickets from another table (visitors_2014) by plotting the data per month per year in a graph. For this i am using the morris js library.
This is the outcome i need

```
data: [ {
            m: 'dec',
            2012: 146,
            2013: 26
        }, {
            m: 'jan',
            2013: 1521,
            2014: 
        }],
```

So how can i combine the mysql query so it's one query

```
SELECT 
prevTbl.MONTH((lastmodified)) as prev_month, 
prevTbl.YEAR((lastmodified)) as prev_year,
prevTbl.COUNT(num_of_tickets) as prev_tickets,
currTbl.MONTH((lastmodified)) as curr_month, 
currTbl.YEAR((lastmodified)) as curr_year,
currTbl.COUNT(num_of_tickets) as curr_tickets
FROM visitors_2013 prevTbl, visitors_2014 currTbl 
GROUP BY 
MONTH((lastmodified)), 
YEAR((lastmodified))
```

Comment: Why you dont do this in php ?

Comment: You can try with `UNION`

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant i was thinking one query would be nicer than two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join your queries:

```
SELECT * FROM ( [your first query here] ) AS data1
LEFT JOIN ( [your second query here] ) AS data2
ON [your relation between the two query here]
```

In your case (not tested):

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT
        `num_of_tickets` AS `tickets2013`,
        MONTH(`lastmodified`) AS `month`
    FROM `visitors_2013`
    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(`lastmodified`)

) AS `data2013`
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT
        `num_of_tickets` AS `tickets2014`,
        MONTH(`lastmodified`) AS `month`
    FROM `visitors_2014`
    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(`lastmodified`)

) AS `data2014`
ON (
    `data2013`.`month`=`data2014`.`month`
)
```

Why do not you store your (actively used) data in the same table (much more simpler)?

Comment: horvath would this group the data by month year this what i am trying right now. only the prev_tickets and curr_tickets are wrong
`SELECT 
MONTH((prevTbl.lastmodified)) as prev_month, 
YEAR((prevTbl.lastmodified)) as prev_year,
COUNT(prevTbl.num_of_tickets) as prev_tickets,
MONTH((currTbl.lastmodified)) as curr_month, 
YEAR((currTbl.lastmodified)) as curr_year,
COUNT(currTbl.num_of_tickets) as curr_tickets
FROM visitors_2013 prevTbl, visitors_2014 currTbl 
GROUP BY 
MONTH((prevTbl.lastmodified)), 
YEAR((prevTbl.lastmodified))`

Comment: i see what you are doing except the tables i have to deal with haven't got a seperate month or year column. I have extract the month/year from a timestamp column, hence the mysql MONTH and YEAR function.

i tried your suggestion by altering the on part
``data2014`.`lastmodified`=`data2015`.`lastmodified`` with no luck

Comment: I removed the wrong `year=year` condition. (The `month` column is created in the subquery.)

Comment: YES! i got some data still need to double check but it looks really good. Thank you for the explanation on the subquery!!

Comment: Storing in one table would be indeed much simpler, i could add a month/year columns. In this case the table 2013 already existed and had a bunch of redundant columns, so i created another table for 2014.